# Comparison of Date in database against current date

Tags: django, django-templates

In my application I have the date of a talk and I want to compare this against the current date to see whether it should display View Attendance Record in my html page. What I am thinking is:

```
if (dateInDB <= currentDate)
    display View Attendance Record
else 
    don't display view attendance record
```

How would i convert this to code? Would I have to do this in the HTML or in an external file that the HTML accesses. If i was doing this in JSPs and Servlets I would make the comparison when it pulls out the date from the database and then set a boolean true but I don't know how to do this in django. 
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.2 supports [boolean operators](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#boolean-operators) in `if` tags. If you are using 1.2 then you can pass a `currentDate` context variable of suitable type to the template and do a boolean comparison.

```
{% if dateInDB <= currentDate %}
    <display>
{% else %}
    <hide>
{% endif %}
```

Alternately you can write a custom filter to test if `dateInDB <= currentDate`.

```
@register.filter
def less_than_current_date(value):
    from datetime import datetime as DT
    return value <= DT.today()

{% if dateInDB|less_than_current_date %}
... etc ...
```

Comment: I used the second way after just reading up on filters they are cool.